# I can not find -no-auto-rehash config in system varaibles

Tags: mysql, global-variables, system, my.cnf

i am trying to find if auto rehash is enabled or not basically trying to find -no-auto-rehash is applied to DB or not. how can i check that.

I tried looking in all system variables but can't find that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`auto-rehash` is not a server variable or a database property. It's a client option.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash

If you want to disable it, start the mysql client like this:

```
mysql --disable-auto-rehash
```

Comment: how can i get that from DB. if it's enabled or not. and i am trying to figure out how can i query "[mysqldump]" config from DB i want to retrieve the quick option value from DB which is under mysqldump in my.cnf

Comment: I understand what you want, but this property is not saved in the database. It has nothing to do with the database, or mysqldump. It's only a feature of the mysql client.